# Need help in configuring email alert in logstash 1.5.4

Tags: logstash

I was using logstash 1.4.2 and this email alert was working fine at that time. Now my system is upgraded to logstash 1.5.4 and logstash is failing because of older settings as below:

```
email { 
        from => "{{Mailfrom}}" 
        match =>  [ "ERROR ALERT", "LOGLEVEL,ERROR" ]   
        subject => "%{matchName}" 
        to => "{{Rcptto}}" 
        via => "smtp" 
        htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><div   
        align='center'>%{message}</div>" 
        options => [ 
               "smtpIporHost", "{{smtpIporHost}}", 
               "port", "{{smtpPort}}", 
               "domain", "{{mailDomain}}", 
               "userName", "{{Mailfrom}}", 
               "password", "{{MailFromPassword}}", 
               "authenticationType", "plain", 
               "starttls", "true" 
       ]
}
```

Now I am getting error as `"You are using a deprecated config setting \"match\" set in email. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc."`

Can anyone help me here, as how should i configure it according to ERROR condition in 1.5.4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Correct configuration:

```
if ([LOGLEVEL] =~ /ERROR/) {
   email { 
        from => "{{Mailfrom}}" 
        subject => "ERROR ALERT" 
        to => "{{Rcptto}}" 
        via => "smtp" 
        htmlbody => "<h2>ERROR ALERT</h2><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{message}</div>" 
        options => [ 
               "smtpIporHost", "{{smtpIporHost}}", 
               "port", "{{smtpPort}}", 
               "domain", "{{mailDomain}}", 
               "userName", "{{Mailfrom}}", 
               "password", "{{MailFromPassword}}", 
               "authenticationType", "plain", 
               "starttls", "true" 
       ]
   }
}
```

### Explanation:

According to the [deprecated documentation of logstash output email](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.9/outputs/email#setting_match) the syntax of `match =>` is:

```
{ "match name", "field.in.event,value.expected, , operand(and/or),field.in.event,value.expected, , or...", "match name", "..." }
```

In your given example the field is `LOGLEVEL` and the expected value is `ERROR`.

From the new documentation of [logstash output email](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html):

> This setting is deprecated in favor of Logstash’s "conditionals"
>   feature If you were using this setting previously, please use
>   conditionals instead.

The corresponding conditional that checks if field `LOGLEVEL` contains `ERROR`:

```
if ([LOGLEVEL] =~ /ERROR/) { }
```

Comment: Thank you, Now I have configured things correctly but when there is error, I dont receive any email... and also there is nothing in logstash.log and logstash.err file, both are blank.

Comment: Probably the condition is never fulfilled. Look at your logs carefully and determine which field (e.g. `LOGLEVEL`)  has which value (e.g. `ERROR`). Then set a proper condition like `if [logLevel] == "Error"`. Note that it is case sensitive. Start logstash over command line to retrieve those fields.

Comment: Yes.. it's working... Now I have another problem, can you please look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371673/not-getting-each-error-email-alert-from-logstash-1-5-4