# Not getting each error email alert from logstash 1.5.4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I have my ELK setup like below:

**HOST1:** Component(which generates log) + Logstash (To send logs to redis)

**HOST2:** Redis + Elasticsearch + Logstash ( To parse data based on grok and send it to elasticsearch on same setup)

**HOST3:** Redis + Elasticsearch + Logstash ( To parse data based on grok and send it to elasticsearch on same setup)

**HOST4:** nginx + Kibana 4

Now when I send one error log line from logstash to redis, I get double entry in Kibana 4. Like below:

[image]

Plus I didnt get any email alert from logstash, although it is configured to send alert when **severity == "Erro"**.

this is part of logstash conf file:

```
output {
elasticsearch { host => ["<ELK IP>"]  port => "9200" protocol => "http" }
if [severity] =~ /Erro/
{
email {
        from => "someone@somedomain.com"
        subject => "Error Alert"
        to => "someone@somedomain.com"
        via => "smtp"
        htmlbody => "<h2>Error Alert1</h2><br/><br/><div
        align='center'>%{message}</div>"
        options => [
               "smtpIporHost", "smtp.office365.com",
               "port", "587",
               "domain", "smtp.office365.com",
               "userName", "someone@somedomain.com",
               "password", "somepasswd",
               "authenticationType", "login",
               "starttls", "true"
       ]
}
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am using following custom grok pattern to parse log line:

```
ABTIMESTAMP %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM2}%{MONTHDAY} %{USERNAME}
ABLOGLEVEL (Note|Erro|Fatl|Warn|Urgt)
ABLOG %{ABTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOST:hostname} %{WORD:servername} %{INT:pid} %{INT:lwp} %{INT:thread} %{ABLOGLEVEL:severity};%{USERNAME:event}\(%{NUMBER:msgcat}/%{NUMBER:msgnum}\)%{GREEDYDATA:greedydata}
```

Any help here as, how to get each email alert for every error log line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the Kibana screenshot, it seems that your `severity` field is an array with two `Erro` values, which is maybe the reason why your check doesn't work, and thus, your email isn't sent.

Comment: thats my concern, when I am putting this line only once, how it is taking array of severity fields which contains multiple values...

Comment: One thing is missing in your question, i.e. how do you parse your log lines?

Comment: I have written custom grok for it as,


`ABTIMESTAMP %{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM2}%{MONTHDAY} %{USERNAME}

ABLOGLEVEL (Note|Erro|Fatl|Warn|Urgt)

ABLOG %{ABTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOST:hostname} %{WORD:servername} %{INT:pid} %{INT:lwp} %{INT:thread} %{ABLOGLEVEL:severity};%{USERNAME:event}\(%{NUMBER:msgcat}/%{NUMBER:msgnum}\)%{GREEDYDATA:greedydata}`

Comment: I think it'd be nice if you could update your question with that config and also add any custom pattern definition you might have.

Comment: Done.. but any clue with my configuration, like what could be issue?

Comment: 1) Can you try to bring down HOST3 and only let HOST2 process your logs? 2) Can you run logstash on HOST2 with `--debug` so we get more insights into the groking process?

Comment: I think, I have resolved it... Actually I was having multiple conf files in logstash/conf.d folder. I removed all unnecessary files and only kept my conf file and now its working. :).
Thank you Val for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it... Actually I was having multiple conf files in logstash/conf.d folder. I removed all unnecessary files and only kept my conf file and now its working. :). Thank you Val for your help